# How to drop and re-create primary keys and foreign keys

Tags: sql-server

i have a database which contains a list of primary keys and foreign keys . i want to drop all foreign keys and primary keys and re-create both of the keys . As of now i have been able to drop and re-create primary keys but unable to add the foreign keys after drop. i am not getting all the foreign keys after drop and re-create.

--query to get all foreign keys with drop statement

```
SELECT    'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ''') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(so.name) + '''))' + CHAR(13)
        + 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(so.name) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + '' 
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.sysobjects so ON (fk.parent_object_id = so.id)
```

--query to get all foreign keys with Add statement

```
SELECT    'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(spo.Name) + ' WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ' FOREIGN KEY(' + QUOTENAME(fkpc.name) + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sro.name) + ' (' + QUOTENAME(fkrc.name) + ')' + CHAR(13)
        + 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(spo.name) + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13)
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk
        INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects spo on (fk.parent_object_id = spo.id)
        INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects sro on (fk.referenced_object_id = sro.id)
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on (fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id)
        INNER JOIN sys.all_columns fkpc on (fkc.parent_object_id = fkpc.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id = fkpc.column_id)
        INNER JOIN sys.all_columns fkrc on (fkc.referenced_object_id = fkrc.object_id and fkc.referenced_column_id = fkrc.column_id)
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: How are you generating the script to recreate the primary keys? Use the same method to generate script to recreate the foreign keys, too!

Comment: I am getting errors like there are no primary key or candiadte key found. but i am getting all primary keys

Comment: The foreign keys are dropped successfully and not added properly

Comment: Just to make sure: You are creating both scripts *prior* to executing the DROP statements, right? ;-) Also, why are you doing this?

Comment: i am doing so and i am doing so to as there has been change in datatype of some columns in most of the tables in database

Comment: i am getting some foreign keys created and some not created

Comment: how to add those foreign keys successfully

Answer (score 0):

To drop all foreign keys you can try to use this script:

```
while(exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'))
begin
 declare @constraints nvarchar(2000)
 SELECT TOP 1 @constraints=('ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']')
 FROM information_schema.table_constraints
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
 exec (@constraints)
 PRINT @constraints
end
GO
```

Do not forget to run it on your database! ))